rate of change between 2 matching values (across many different rows)
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:
  A    B    count
---   ---   -----
  X    A1      10
  Y    A1       5
  X    A2       1
  Y    A2      50
  X    A3       2
  Y    A4      90

There are only 2 different possible values in column A, but there are many different values for column B. I am interested in the percent change of matching values of column B between X and Y rows.
So, for example, in the above, since A1 appears in column B for both X and Y rows, and the value goes from 10 to 5, the percent change for A1 is 100* (5-10)/10) = -50%
Also note that the rows with B=A3 and B=A4 only occur a single time, so they should be reported in some special way (since the percent change formula doesn't work with a single value).
From looking at the pct_change function it seems like it expects more than just 2 different values in column A. And I'm new to pandas, so not sure about good ways of comparing values of B across the entire frame.
I could iterate over it in python, create a dict for X rows and a dict for Y rows, then do the caclucation for each entry (and report entries that are only in X or only in Y), but was hoping there is some panda-fu that will churn it out more quickly.

Code
Since you want the values compared for each item anyway, pivoting seems better. You could use the pivot function, but it throws an error on bad data where there are more than 2 rows in the combination of A and B, so I used the pivot_table function.
out = (df.pivot_table(values='count', index='B', columns='A', aggfunc='sum')
         .pct_change(axis=1, fill_method=None)['Y']
)

out
B
A1   -0.50
A2   49.00
A3     NaN
A4     NaN
Name: Y, dtype: float64

The code above uses a sum when there are more than 2 rows(becuz column name is count), but you can change this depending on how you want to handle duplicate data.

This is matching what I got with my extra python work. So, looks good.

A possible solution:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y"],
        "B": ["A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A4"],
        "count": [10, 5, 1, 50, 2, 90],
    }
)

df["pct"] = df.groupby("B")["count"].pct_change()

   A   B  count   pct
0  X  A1     10   NaN
1  Y  A1      5  -0.5
2  X  A2      1   NaN
3  Y  A2     50  49.0
4  X  A3      2   NaN
5  Y  A4     90   NaN


Looks like it expects column A sorted, which I can do, but something else isn't quite right.  When I try it on my larger dataset (200 rows), I see every row in the dataframe gets a pct value, but I was expecting (like in the example) that only the 2nd occurrence of a value in column B will have a pct value.

@teg95 Yes, values in column 'A' should be sorted, as in the example included in the question. As for your second issue, it would indicate that the example is not representative of the real data. I've edited my answer to include the code I used to create the dataframe, so you can maybe spot any differences.
